# TCL passing lists of regexes through command line

Tags: regex, tcl, command-line-arguments

I would like to use a command line argument to pass a list of regular expressions into my TCL script (currently using TCL 8.4 but will be using 8.6 later). Right now, my script has an optional flag that you can set called `-spec` which is meant to be followed by the list of regexes. (And it has some other optional flags as well.)

So here is the sort of thing I would like to be able to do from the command line:

```
>tclsh84 myscript.tcl /some/path -someflag somearg -spec "(f\d+)_ (m\d+)_"
```

and then in my script, I would have something like this:

```
set spec [lindex $argv [expr {[lsearch $argv "-spec"] + 1}]]
foreach item $spec {
    do some stuff
}
```

I have it working except for the part where I pass in a list of regexes. The above method doesn't work for passing in regexes... However, without the quotes, it behaves like two arguments instead of one, and braces doesn't seem to work right either. Is there a better solution? (I'm kind of a newb...)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When parsing command line options, it's easiest to have a simple stage to take all that apart and turn it into something easier to work with in the rest of the code. Perhaps like this:

```
# Deal with mandatory first argument
if {$argc < 1} {
    puts stderr "Missing filename"
    exit 1
}
set filename [lindex $argv 0]

# Assumes exactly one flag value per option
foreach {key value} [lrange $argv 1 end] {
    switch -glob -- [string tolower $key] {
        -spec {
            # Might not be the best choice, but it gives you a cheap
            # space-separated list without the user having to know Tcl's
            # list syntax...
            set RElist [split $value]
        }

        -* {
            # Save other options in an array for later; might be better
            # to do more explicit parsing of course
            set option([string tolower [string range $key 1 end]]) $value
        }

        default {
            # Problem: option doesn't start with hyphen! Print error message
            # (which could be better I suppose) and do a failure exit
            puts stderr "problem with option parsing..."
            exit 1
        }
    }
}

# Now you do the rest of the processing of your code.
```

Then you can check if any of the REs match some string like this:

```
proc anyMatches {theString} {
    global RElist
    foreach re $RElist {
        if {[regexp $re $theString]} {
            return 1
        }
    }
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Some of these things can be done a little more neatly from 8.5 onwards (8.4 is now really old) but that's finessing.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think this is a much better way of doing it than the way I had!

Answer (score 0):

Use one -spec per pattern like find, grep, sed, etc do.

```
set indices [lsearch -all -regexp $argv {^-{1,2}spec$}]
if {[llength $indices] && [expr {[lindex $indices end] + 1}] >= $argc} {
    # bad use
}
foreach index $indices {
    set pattern [lindex $argv [incr index]]
    # ...
}
```